# Move from first character of function declaration to ending brace in VIM

Tags: vim

If I have a function declared as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    blahblahlbah;
}
```

Is there anyway to move from the "p" in `public` to the ending "}" of the function?

It can be assumed that the method body is of considerable length and does contain curly braces if that makes a difference.

Thanks!

Comment: So the result would be `ublic static ... { ... } p` ?

Comment: No, that the cursor would be on the "}" on the last line

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. Looks like I completely ignored the "from" word and thought you were trying to modify the text. I even edited your question! Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this key sequence: `f{%`  Should do it.

Comment: Ah. Two movements.. Guess that should have been obvious.. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is not a few ways to accomplish the movement.

The most appropriate motion command is

```
]M
```

which is short and *to the point*: It moves the cursor to the end of the next
method in a Java-like source code.

There are also three satellite motions that together with `]M` give
possibility to jump to next or previous starts and ends of methods, see `:help
]m` and below.  Therefore, in addition to `]M`, in this situation one can
issue

```
]m%
```

The rest of the answer contains discussion of some tricks that should be used
only if the aforementioned motion commands for some reason have failed to
solve the problem in your case.

Another simple idea to take advantage of is to jump over the argument list,
find the next opening curly brace and move to its closing counterpart,

```
%l%
```

or

```
f{%
```

or even

> `/%`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`%`

A similar idea to move the cursor to the very beginning of the method's body
and than jump to the next unmatched closing curly brace leads to the following
command,

```
j]}
```

Note, though, that three of the last four commands work only if the function
header is a single line.  If that is not the case, they need modifications.

Under some assumptions on the code formatting, it is also possible to achieve
the same result using plain-text-oriented movements.  If the opening curly
brace is the last character on the method header line, one can use

```
$%
```

or

```
g_%
```

if that brace is the last *non-blank* character.

In conclusion, stick to the `]M` movement as far as it works for you (it
should, in the vast majority of cases), fall back upon tricks based on
combinations of other text motion commands, otherwise.

Comment: The `]M` is nice as well since it enables you to put your cursor on the first line of a function and hit `zf]M` to fold that function.  Very nice! Thanks!

Comment: @3321thec:  Indeed, it has all the power of a motion command!  And unlike many other combinations of movements, this motion works for multi-line method headers, too.  It is a little built-in gem for Java-like source code editing in Vim, isn't it?

Comment: For me both ]m and ]M are behaving the same way. Both jump to the opening brace { and not the closing brace. Is there some setting that I should check.

Comment: @Ronin420:  First of all, check current filetype of the buffer you are editing: `:set ft?`.

Comment: @ib. I was trying it out for a C++ file (containing class definitions) . Wish C++ had something similar. ][ and ]{,]} is nice but didn't find anything like ]M

Answer (score 1):

`/{` will take you to the opening brace and `%` will jump to the matching closing one.

Answer (score 1):

`][` moves to the next `}` in the first column.  So this will work for you as long as your function is properly indented.

See `:help ][` and `:help section`

I use this while searching through a file and my cursor is positioned over a particular search result in the middle of some long function.  Often, I'll want to know which function I'm in so `][%` gets me to the function signature, and then `n` returns me to the search result where I started.